# Passar valor de um select para parametro GET de um link

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, get

Olá, necessitava passar o valor de um  para um parametro de um link, isto para ser enviado via GET. Estou a usa a framework codeigniter.

Segue o trecho de código que tenho:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 form-num-sala">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="margin-left:-55px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Designação da sala</label>
                <br/>
                <select name="designacaoSala" class="form-control">
                    <?php foreach ($designacaoSala as $numsala) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $numsala->numerosala ?>">
                            <?php echo $numsala->numerosala ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" style="margin-left:-25px;">
            <label>Aplicar</label>
            <br/>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('utilizador/addSalaEspacoEvento/?idplano='.$hDefenidos->idplanoespacoevento.'&numerosala='); ?>">
                <button class="form-control"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

A variável `$hDefenidos->idplanoespacoevento` vem de cima mas a variável &numerosala deveria vir do select com o nome "designacaosala" e ser a dicionada ao seguinte link:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('utilizador/addSalaEspacoEvento/?idplano='.$hDefenidos->idplanoespacoevento.'&numerosala='); ?>">
    <button class="form-control"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
</a>
```

Alguém pode dar uma força? obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Se não houver problema em passar por POST e não GET, você pode fazer assim: No lugar de passar as variáveis em um link, passa-se os valores no `form`. Quando se usa a url no codeigniter pode-se pegar os valores pelos segmentos (cada "/" separa um segmento, onde o primeiro vem logo após a url base do site). Exemplo: www.site.com/segmento1/segmento2/segmento3/... onde *segmento1* é o nome do controlador, *segmento2* o nome do método do controlador e o *segmento3* um parâmetro para o método. O valor do select você pega via POST.

**VIEW**: (vou utilizar apenas a parte funcional desconsiderando as div's de formatação)

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=site_url('utilizador/addSalaEspacoEvento/'.$hDefenidos->idplanoespacoevento); ?>">
    <select name="designacaoSala" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach ($designacaoSala as $numsala) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $numsala->numerosala ?>">
                <?php echo $numsala->numerosala ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Aplicar" />
</form>
```

**CONTROLADOR CODEIGNITER**:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Utilizador extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function addSalaEspacoEvento($idplanoespacoevento) {
        $valorDoSelect = $this->input->post('designacaoSala');

        ...
    }
}
```

Caso esteja usando as rotas do codeigniter, sugiro revisá-las caso tenha problemas em achar o método na requisição. Vale lembrar que a lib session deve está carregada, ou no controlador ou no arquivo autoload.

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pelo que entendi você quer passar o valor do option da sala selecionada para a URL do link, não? Fiz uma solução em jquery. A lógica seria: pegar o link exibido pelo PHP, pegar a sala selecionada e atribuir no link quando outra opção for selecionada.
Obs: omiti os códigos PHP. Adicionei uma classe para o select e um id para a tag do link, pra selecioná-los com jquery.
Link para o código: (https://jsfiddle.net/tr139sv8/)